# CGAL installation no ALL_BUILD.exe Window

Tags: windows, cgal

Hi there guys I'm trying to install CGAL4.13. When I use cmake to create CGAL.sln file the configuration says is done, and I do generated afterwards. However I do see that it says that I'm missing a couple of stuff:

1)Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured

2)ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR

However cmake does generate the CGAL.sln, I do build them and they don't give any errors. But when I try to run them, I have the following message:

Unable to start program: C:\dev\CGAL-4.13\build\Debug\ALL_BUILD can't be found.I seach for that path and is empty, I can't find the .exe file anywhere. I don't know why is not creating it since when I build it doesn't show any errors.

I followed this way of installing: https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html . I've tried everything I still have the same error. Can you please help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL_BUILD is not an executable target. Just right clic on a demo, test or example in your solution and execute it, don't run the default target in MSVC.

Comment: I'm new to c++ coding and to visual studio. I don't know how to run the examples after building them with cmake, what do you mean by right click?

Comment: Basically, you run cmake, this should create a .sln file, that you will run with Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, you should have a list of all the targets of your project, with ALL_BUILD in the first position.  it is called the Solution Explorer. In this list, you can find names called test_blah_blah, or blah_blah_example. Those are executables. You can right clic on the name to get a contextual menu, and execute only the specified target from it.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot, I feel super dumb asking this basic stuff. But thanks I appriciate it!