# How to fix "Unable to start an example program using cgal and boost library in VS 16 2019. Cannot create the ALL_BUILD file."?

Tags: visual-c++, cgal

I'm having trouble in running a program with CGAL and Boost library on Visual Studio 16. It shows a message saying the 'ALL_BUILD' path is not available, hence it is unable to start the program. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CGAL installation no ALL\_BUILD.exe Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164276/cgal-installation-no-all-build-exe-window)

Answer (score 0):

ALL_BUILD is a convenience target that builds all targets. It is not an executable. Select another target in the solution, like a test or an example,  to run.